# phpAdmin Query, list clients with last order placed x days ago

Tags: zen-cart

Im not that much familiar with zencart table structure and I'm a newbie at Mysql, I'm looking for the best whet to list all clients with last order purchased more then 30 days ago or to the past of a certain date but none forward to that date, can someone help me build this query please?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT C.customers_id, C.customers_firstname, C.customers_lastname,  
O.date_purchased, O.orders_id, O.order_total, OS.orders_status_name
    FROM  orders O
    LEFT join customers C on C.customers_id = O.customers_id
    LEFT join orders_status OS on OS.orders_status_id=O.orders_status
    WHERE 
       O.date_purchased BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

This will display customer name and OrderID, Total of Order and Status of Order for 30 days ago to current date.